# Use a subfield selector dynamically with ProcessWire/Smarty

Tags: smarty, processwire

I am using the [Smarty Templating](http://modules.processwire.com/modules/smarty-templating/) module with [ProcessWire](http://processwire.com/) (v2.1.6) and I have two templates `Teacher` and `Subject`. The `Teacher` template has a field (type is multiple pages) referencing the subjects a teacher can teach. Accessing those in Smarty is straightforward, as can be seen in the `Teacher` template:

```
{foreach from=$page->subjects item=subject}
    <li><a href="{$subject->url}">{$subject->title}</a></li>
{/foreach}
```

However, users of the website should also be able to view all the teachers for a `Subject`:

```
{foreach from=$pages->find('template=Teacher,subjects.title={$page->title}') item=teacher}
    <li><a href="{$teacher->url}">{$teacher->title}</a></li>
{/foreach}
```

This uses a [subfield selector](https://processwire.com/api/selectors/#subfield) `subjects.title` and tries to expand the operand dynamically (`{$page->title}`).

First I thought that the dynamic expansion is the problem, but if I replace it with a constant string, the subfield selector does not work either (the foreach does not generate anything):

```
{foreach from=$pages->find('template=Teacher,subjects.title="History"') item=teacher}
```

Interestingly, the very similar [count selector](https://processwire.com/api/selectors/#count) does work:

```
{foreach from=$pages->find('template=Teacher,subjects.count > 1') item=teacher}
```

Comment: Not sure how to help, but you'd probably be better off asking in the forums.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know anything about Smarty, but `{$page->title}` can’t be expanded because it is inside a single-quoted string. Try using double quotes:

```
    $pages->find("template=Teacher, subjects.title={$page->title}")
```

See the [PHP manual on variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in strings for details.

I would also suggest selecting by `subjects.id=$page->id` or `subjects.name=$page->name`, since those fields will be unique and don’t use output formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This is the **workaround** I used (but I am still interested in an actual solution):

```
{foreach from=$pages->find("template=Teacher") item=teacher}
    {foreach from=$teacher->subjects item=subject}
        {if $subject->title == $page->title}
             <li><a href="{$teacher->url}">{$teacher->title}</a></li>
[...]
```